# How to set proxy "None" under Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, proxy

I am trying to make wifi work under my Windows 7.

My computer has dual system: Windows 7 and Ubuntu. Under Ubuntu, the wifi works well, the setting of the proxy is `None`:
[image]

However, Under Windows 7, the following setting does NOT work:
[image]

Sorry for the Chinese characters, the main idea is all the boxes for the proxy have been unchecked. But it gives this error when I load a web page:

[image]

Besides, the wifi itself doesn't have any problem. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Could anyone help?

**Edit:**
Following the comment of @DaJF, I did some tests:

1) `ping` works well
2) `nslookup www.kuhao360.com` does NOT work

Here is the screenshot of `ipconfig/all` under Windows (sorry for Chinese characters again):
[image]
[image]
[image]
and `ipconfig` under Ubuntu:
[image]

Comment: ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED points to a DNS issue.

Comment: please see my update...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Open the commandline in windows (Win+R, then type "cmd" and hit enter)**

- Can you ping? Type `ping 110.249.215.46` (this is the IP address of kuhau360.com) and hit enter. Does this give you `"Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=30ms TTL=50"`? (`bytes`, `time` and `TTL` are most likely different) No? Report back with a screenshot of the output, and of `ipconfig/all` in windows, and `ifconfig` in ubuntu. Else, continue.
- Is DNS correctly configured? Type `ipconfig/flushdns` to flush your cache. This is not really necessary, but this makes sure any subsequent dns-requests aren't read from the cache.
  Next, type `nslookup www.kuhao360.com`. If this doesn't give you an IP address, there's something wrong with the way windows tries to look it up. Please report back with a output from both `ipconfig/all` in windows, and `ifconfig` in ubuntu, so that they can be compared.

Ok, so there appears to be nothing wrong with your connection, which is what I expected. I see that you're using servers in france (89.2.0.1) for dns. Did you configure this? 
Anyway, you can set your dns servers to what your router gives you by typing Win+R, and entering `ncpa.cpl` and hitting enter. This opens your Network Connections Panel (I'm guessing ncpa.cpl stands for '**n**etwork**c**onnections**pa**nel.**c**ontrol**p**ane**l**).
Now find the one that says *Intel (R) WiFi Link 5100 AGN* like below: 
(I happen to have the same one in my laptop.)
[image: Network_Connections]
Right-click it, and select "Properties". Now select *Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)* and click "Properties", like below:
[image: Wireless_Connection]
Then make sure yours looks like the one below, both "Obtain ... address automatically" selected:
[image: DHCP_Setting]
Click "Ok". Close the *Intel (R) WiFi Link 5100 AGN* dialog too. This should fix it. You might have to close your browser and reopen it for it to take effect.

Comment: I've updated my answer as well. Hope I helped.

Answer (score 0):

Check your proxy settings in the browser you are using. In IE - Internet options->connections-> Lan settings
In FF -Tools->Options->Advance->Network->Connection